# Problem in sending and receiving date from C# code to SQL Server procedure

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I am generating a report through sending some parameter from C# code to a SQL Server stored procedure. I am sending a string value and two date values as a SQL Server procedure parameters, but I having some problems with the date parameter. I have checked my SQL Server stored procedure; when manually passing a value, it is returning the correct results, but when I am passing the parameter value from my code, it is showing nothing in report.

SQL Server stored procedure:

```
[GetLedger]
    (@optb VARCHAR(50),
     @startsession DATE,
     @endsession DATE)
AS
    DECLARE @openingtable
    DECLARE @strtdt DATE
    DECLARE @enddate DATE
    DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(MAX)
BEGIN
    SET @openingtable = @optb
    SET @strtdt = @startsession
    SET @enddate = @endsession
    SET @query = N'SELECT  l.trandate,l.voucherno,l.itemno,l.itemname,o.opening + COALESCE(SUM(l.recieve - l.returnback - l.issue) OVER (PARTITION BY l.itemno ORDER BY l.trandate,seq ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING),0) AS opening,l.recieve,l.returnback,l.issue,o.opening + SUM(l.recieve - l.returnback - l.issue) OVER (PARTITION BY l.itemno ORDER BY l.trandate,seq) AS balance,l.to_dept,l.remarks
FROM @openingstock o
INNER JOIN
(
SELECT trandate,voucherno,itemno,itemname,to_dept,remarks,isnull(recieve,0) AS recieve,isnull(issue,0) AS issue,isnull(returnback,0) AS returnback,
row_number() over (partition by itemno,trandate order by itemno) as seq
FROM @ledgertable
) l
ON l.itemno = o.itemno
where l.trandate between CONVERT(Date,''' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),@strtdt, 101)+''', 101) and CONVERT(DATE,'''+ CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),DATEADD(DD,1,@enddate),101) + ''', 101)
ORDER BY l.itemno,trandate'

    EXECUTE(@query)
END
```

C# code is:

```
private ledgerdt GetData(string p1,string p2,string p3)
{
    string DateString = p2;
    IFormatProvider culture = new CultureInfo("en-US", true);
    DateTime pp2 = DateTime.ParseExact(DateString, "yyyy-MM-dd", culture);
    string DateString2 = p2;
    IFormatProvider culture2 = new CultureInfo("en-US", true);
    DateTime pp3 = DateTime.ParseExact(DateString, "yyyy-MM-dd", culture2);

    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conString))
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("GetLedger", con);

        using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
        {
            cmd.Connection = con;
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@optb", p1);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@startsession", pp2.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@endsession", pp3.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));

            sda.SelectCommand = cmd;

            using (ledgerdt ds = new ledgerdt())
            {
                sda.Fill(ds, "ledgerdt");
                return ds;
            }
        }
}
```

Please tell the solution..... I know that I am doing something wrong in data type.

Comment: Why are you doing the conversions between dates and strings, both in your C# and your sql? If its a date, pass it as a date, and do your selection as a date.

Comment: You should check out [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) and stop using `.AddWithValue()` - it can lead to unexpected and surprising results...

Comment: @TomC i am writing .ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") portion because I thought there might be some problem because of date format.

Comment: @marc_s when i was passing without conversion it wast throwing an error

Comment: `DATE` and `DATETIME` in SQL Server **doesn't have** any format - it's an 8-byte binary value. And if you have a date, and your stored procedure expects a date - just pass the date and don't convert back and forth to and from string - use the **most appropriate** datatype, always.

Comment: Also don't think you need to construct a query then execute it in your stored proc. Why not just run the query directly. You definitely don't need to be converting the date parameters back to strings.

Comment: It would be good to see the complete stored procedure because what you have posted appears to be just a segment, including table variables that are not defined.

Comment: @TomC i am creating stored procedure because i need to pass tables from different session so i am using dynamic sql here to pass the table name as a string and receive this name in sql procedure that is why i am creating sql procedure. I have posted full sql procedure.

Answer (score 0):

Added the code using Add instead of AddWithValue:

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conString))
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("GetLedger", con))
using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
{
        cmd.Connection = con;
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SQLParameter("@optb", Data.SqlDbType.VarChar);
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SQLParameter("@startsession", Data.SqlDbType.DateTime));

        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SQLParameter("@endsession", Data.SqlDbType.DateTime));
        command.Parameters("@optb").Value = p1;
        command.Parameters("@startsession").Value = pp2;
        command.Parameters("@startsession").Value = pp3;

        sda.SelectCommand = cmd;

        using (ledgerdt ds = new ledgerdt())
        {
            sda.Fill(ds, "ledgerdt");
            return ds;
        }
}
```

Comment: That's find on the C# side, but the stored proc needs work too. Its still converting dates to strings.

Comment: @TomC could you please tell me the right answer for my procedure.

Comment: can you share your data that you are trying to pass and also debug it to see

Comment: Its a bit difficult because the proc as its shown includes table variables that are not defined. Think its just a segment not the complete proc.

Comment: @Gauravsa it is not giving any error but not giving any result in report while when i am passing the same value at sql server it is giving right result.

Comment: @TomC you are just commenting back, please do not comment if you can not give any answer. I have posted full segment it is another thing that you are not able to understand i think. thanks

Comment: @Gauravsa i also want to tell you that i am calling GetData function from another function where i am giving the following code to define the path of .rdlc report code is: ReportViewer1.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local;
                ReportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = Server.MapPath("~/Report1.rdlc");  ledgerdt ds3 = GetData(optb,startdate,enddate);

                ReportDataSource datasource = new ReportDataSource("ledgerdt", ds3.Tables[0]);
                ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
                ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(datasource);

Comment: @Gauravsa when i debugging my code i am getting all the date in dataset i.e. ds3 but i don't know why it is not shoing in my .rdlc report

Comment: Can u add ReportViewer1.RefreshReport();

Comment: Add it after adding the datasource line

Comment: Also, can u see the report? Like the path ~reportname is correct?

Comment: thanks for your reply. i have got the solution. there was a problem with my datatable. thank you very much.